# I'm fairly new to JSON, and I'm trying to get the user data from google + JSOn Code is

Tags: php, json

I'm fairly new to JSON, and I'm trying to get the user data from google +
JSOn Code is 
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people?query=saurabh+sharma&key=AIzaSyADJjj8IeKuGb-woleHKTVouSlvAJUpTrs

Please help me to retrive the user profile.. in php

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people?query=saurabh+sharma&key=AIzaSyADJjj8IeKuGb-woleHKTVouSlvAJUpTrs')));`

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed a bit of a mixed potato-puree (=confusion) between arrays and objects. That JSON is entirely object, except for the array 'items', which is an array of... objects.

Try this:

```
<?php
$strUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people?query=saurabh+sharma&key=AIzaSyADJjj8IeKuGb-woleHKTVouSlvAJUpTrs";
$strContents = file_get_contents($strUrl);
$objPeopleFeed = json_decode($strContents);

//It's an array of objects, so:
echo "<h1>{$objPeopleFeed->title}</h1>";
foreach($objPeopleFeed->items as $objUser)
{
    echo "
<p>
    <img src='{$objUser->image->url}' />
    <a href='{$objUser->url}'>{$objUser->displayName}</a>
    <i>{$objUser->objectType}</i>
</p>";
}
?>
```

What it does: It gets the contents from the web (which is JSON), interpretes it as JSON into valid PHP structures. From the structure, we print the title as a H1 header. From the items, which is an array, we loop through each one, print the image src from `$objUser->image->url`, print the user link $objUser->url with its name `$objUser->displayName`, and optionally its type of object `$objUser->objectType` that is registered on Google.

Because everything is kind of objects, you use the object to variable syntax '`->xyz`' instead of array indexes '`["xyz"]`', and I guess you got stuck there. The `$objPeopleFeed->items` is a non-associative array, so you use numbers to loop through the items (`$objPeopleFeed->items[0]` for the first item, 1 for the second, etc...). As a final cookie to you, you can use `count($objPeopleFeed->items)` as a results count.

Comment: thanks for help...
i want to display next page result from json data with next pagetoken...

Comment: Thats something I dont know. I will need to look at the googleapi documentation, and you will probably find somewhere a description of how to add a parameter like page=xyz into the url. This should give you a heads up